# Do I need antiforgery in ASP.Web API using Bearer Auth and 3rd party SSO?

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, single-sign-on, bearer-token, antiforgerytoken

I'm working on a Web API project, which uses JWT token and Bearer Auth for Authentication. The token is supplied to the front-end page from a third party SSO, stored in the session storage, and added to the Authorization header of the requests sent to the API. As far as I've been able to figure out from reading about antiforgery, I don't need antiforgery token in this scenario, since the Authorization header is not auto-filled by the browser.

However, my company uses Coverity for code analysis and one of the issues it raised was CSRF risk. In regards to that I have two questions:

1. Does the fact that I know that front-end page stores the JWT token in session storage means I don't need to use antiforgery tokens? Or is it better to not rely on that knowledge, since that can be changed by future changes to that page?
2. Could the use of SSO as the token issuer be a risk factor for CSRF attack? This SSO service is used extensively by the company, however different web apps use different SSO service instances (but front-end page and my API use the same SSO instance, to be able to authenticate with the API by being authenticated in the front-end page)

Don't know if that's relevant, but the API and the front-end page share the same SLD, but have different lower-level domains, and the API has CORS enabled, only allowing requests from front-end page's domain, allowing any methods, headers and allowing credentials.

P.S. I'm not 100% sure if I used all terms correctly, I'm somewhat new to the web security

Comment: From [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0#token-based-authentication) we can see "Don't be concerned about CSRF vulnerability if the token is stored in the browser's local storage." But your front-end page stores the JWT token in session storage .

Comment: @QingGuo session storage is the same as local storage except shorter lived, afaik